# how to catch event from a custom component

Tags: java, swing, events, custom-component

I can catch event in a custom component using processKeyEvent method like this way.

```
class CustomComp extends JPanel
{
   @Override
   public void processKeyEvent(final KeyEvent event)
    {
     if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
      {
          //do somthing here
      }
   }
}
```

is there any alternative ways to do that?

Comment: Add a key listener to the component.

Comment: why do you want to extend a JButton? It's as button-ness as it can get :-)

Comment: I took JButton as an example.if it is wrong let's say JPanel. I edited the question

Comment: then: what do you want to achieve? If you really want it, have a look at the sources of swing components in the jdk :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The preferred method would probably be to use the [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) API